# Multi part identifier can not be bound on left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following query that I am trying to add a condition onto a Left Outer Join, however the aliased table (B) is erroring because it can not be bound.

If I add the condition into the WHERE criteria it works, however I believe this is filtering more rows than I want to be, so I really want to include it in the outer join.

```
SELECT  A.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.DESCR, 
(CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)), A.PO_ID, A.VENDOR_ID,
 B.LINE_NBR, B.INV_ITEM_ID, E.DESCR, B.ITM_ID_VNDR, B.CATEGORY_ID, B.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
 B.MFG_ID, B.MFG_ITM_ID, C.MERCHANDISE_AMT, C.QTY_PO, C.MERCH_AMT_BSE, C.ACCOUNT,
 E.CATEGORY_ID, F.DESCR60, E.ITEM_FIELD_C10_A, E.ITEM_FIELD_C10_B, H.INVOICE_ID, H.INVOICE_DT, H.VOUCHER_ID
  FROM  PS_PO_HDR A 

  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER_LINE G ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER H ON G.VOUCHER_ID = H.VOUCHER_ID AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT

  ,PS_PO_LINE B, PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB C, PS_BUS_UNIT_TBL_FS D,
  (PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL E 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_ITM_CAT_TBL F ON  E.SETID = F.SETID AND F.CATEGORY_ID = E.CATEGORY_ID )


    WHERE ( A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
     AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND B.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
     AND B.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
     AND A.PO_DT BETWEEN '2018-12-05' AND '2018-12-12' 
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND E.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
     AND F.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ITM_CAT_TBL F_ED 
        WHERE F.SETID = F_ED.SETID 
          AND F.CATEGORY_TYPE = F_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
          AND F.CATEGORY_CD = F_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
          AND F.CATEGORY_ID = F_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
          AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)))

LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER_LINE G ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT **AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR**
```

Error:

> The multi-part identifier "B.LINE_NBR" could not be bound.

I believe this is occuring because the PS_PO_LINE B table is not declared until after this join. If I move the join to be at the bottom of the FROM section, then I get bound errors on `PS_PO_HDR A` and still `PS_PO_LINE B`, so I'm not sure what I can do to avoid using the criteria in the WHERE section. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Agree with Gordon...after all, it has been in the standards since 1992, more than 25 years ago.

Comment: Please rephrase your query and don't merge old-school joins with modern joins in the same query. It's a mess to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are mixing in join syntaxes. [Don't use old style joins.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

If you reformat your code, you'll see your issue.

```
SELECT
   A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
   D.DESCR,
   (
      CONVERT(CHAR(10), A.PO_DT, 121)
   ),
   A.PO_ID,
   A.VENDOR_ID,
   B.LINE_NBR,      
   B.INV_ITEM_ID,
   E.DESCR,
   B.ITM_ID_VNDR,
   B.CATEGORY_ID,
   B.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
   B.MFG_ID,
   B.MFG_ITM_ID,
   C.MERCHANDISE_AMT,
   C.QTY_PO,
   C.MERCH_AMT_BSE,
   C.ACCOUNT,
   E.CATEGORY_ID,
   F.DESCR60,
   E.ITEM_FIELD_C10_A,
   E.ITEM_FIELD_C10_B,
   H.INVOICE_ID,
   H.INVOICE_DT,
   H.VOUCHER_ID 
FROM
   PS_PO_HDR A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER_LINE G 
      ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER H 
      ON G.VOUCHER_ID = H.VOUCHER_ID 
      AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT,
      PS_PO_LINE B,
      PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB C,
      PS_BUS_UNIT_TBL_FS D,
      (
         PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL E 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            PS_ITM_CAT_TBL F 
            ON E.SETID = F.SETID 
            AND F.CATEGORY_ID = E.CATEGORY_ID 
      )
WHERE
   (
      A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
      AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND B.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
      AND B.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
      AND A.PO_DT BETWEEN '2018-12-05' AND '2018-12-12' 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND E.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
      AND F.EFFDT = 
      (
         SELECT
            MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) 
         FROM
            PS_ITM_CAT_TBL F_ED 
         WHERE
            F.SETID = F_ED.SETID 
            AND F.CATEGORY_TYPE = F_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
            AND F.CATEGORY_CD = F_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
            AND F.CATEGORY_ID = F_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
            AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, GETDATE(), 121), 1, 10)
      )
   )
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER_LINE G 
      ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT **
      AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR*
```

The very bottom of your code you have:

```
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER_LINE G 
      ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT **
      AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR*
```

Assuming the `*` isn't actually in your code (cause that would also cause a problem), the `JOIN` statements come *before* the `WHERE` clause. This one is *after* the `WHERE` clause. You need to move it.

After changing everything to explicit join syntax, and removing some bogus commas and unnecessary parentheses, here is a stab at what you want. Just check the `JOIN` clauses where I have comments.

```
SELECT
   A.BUSINESS_UNIT,
   D.DESCR,
   (
      CONVERT(CHAR(10), A.PO_DT, 121)
   ),
   A.PO_ID,
   A.VENDOR_ID,
   B.LINE_NBR,      
   B.INV_ITEM_ID,
   E.DESCR,
   B.ITM_ID_VNDR,
   B.CATEGORY_ID,
   B.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
   B.MFG_ID,
   B.MFG_ITM_ID,
   C.MERCHANDISE_AMT,
   C.QTY_PO,
   C.MERCH_AMT_BSE,
   C.ACCOUNT,
   E.CATEGORY_ID,
   F.DESCR60,
   E.ITEM_FIELD_C10_A,
   E.ITEM_FIELD_C10_B,
   H.INVOICE_ID,
   H.INVOICE_DT,
   H.VOUCHER_ID 
FROM
   PS_PO_HDR A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER_LINE G 
      ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER H 
      ON G.VOUCHER_ID = H.VOUCHER_ID 
      AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT = H.BUSINESS_UNIT

    /*BEGIN code taken from where clause */
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_PO_LINE B  
      ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND A.PO_ID = B.PO_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB C
      ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND B.PO_ID = C.PO_ID 
      AND B.LINE_NBR = C.LINE_NBR 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_BUS_UNIT_TBL_FS D
      ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_MASTER_ITEM_TBL E
      ON  E.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
      /*END code taken from where clause */

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_ITM_CAT_TBL F 
      ON E.SETID = F.SETID 
      AND F.CATEGORY_ID = E.CATEGORY_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_VOUCHER_LINE G 
      ON A.PO_ID = G.PO_ID 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = G.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND G.LINE_NBR = B.LINE_NBR
WHERE

      A.PO_DT BETWEEN '2018-12-05' AND '2018-12-12' 
      AND F.EFFDT = 
      (
         SELECT
            MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) 
         FROM
            PS_ITM_CAT_TBL F_ED 
         WHERE
            F.SETID = F_ED.SETID 
            AND F.CATEGORY_TYPE = F_ED.CATEGORY_TYPE 
            AND F.CATEGORY_CD = F_ED.CATEGORY_CD 
            AND F.CATEGORY_ID = F_ED.CATEGORY_ID 
            AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR, GETDATE(), 121), 1, 10)
      )
```